# static content not served properly whenTwo react apps hosted behind HAProxy

Tags: javascript, reactjs, haproxy

Same server hosts 2 react apps onports 300 and 4007
I would like to forward the client request to the profile app
through the following haproxy config.

```
frontend http_front
bind *:80
acl has_special_uri path_beg /profile
use_backend manfrontend if has_special_uri
stats uri /haproxy?stats
default_backend http_rear

backend http_rear
balance roundrobin
server wbs1.com 10.154.22.33:3000 check

backend manfrontend
balance roundrobin
server webC 10.154.22.33:4007   check
```

The issue is that the application does not render properly after the forwarding.(ie when the user clicks http://10.154.22.33/profile)

The weird thing is that the static content is retrieved from the default backend.
What I expect is it should try to render static pages from **manfrontend** in haproxy config

When haproxy is disabled it runs without any problems.

Any help is deeply appreciated.

The error messages are as follows.
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Implementing a rule based on referer header made the trick for me.
Similar application behind a proxy caused content to be served from different applications.

```
    frontend http_front
    bind *:80 
    mode http
    
    
    acl profile_uri path_dir -i /management/profile
    acl mfe_referer hdr_dir(referer) -i /management/profile
    use_backend man if profile_uri  
    use_backend man if  mfe_referer 
     
    default_backend med
    
    
    
    backend man
    server MAN x.x.x.x 

backend med
server MEDIA  y.y.y.y
```

Comment: inspect each request on google chrome console to check header info individually and then implement rules accordingly.